# ¿Cómo "switchear" dos vistas HTML dependiendo el tamaño de la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy desarrollando una página de prueba y tengo en una de ellas un boligrama hecho con canvas y en la otra tengo un accordeon. Lo que debo hacer es que en pantallas grandes, digamos una relución de 800 * 600 o mayor debe mostrarse el boligrama, pero un tamaño menor a este, debe cambiarse por el accordeon. ¿Alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Soy nuevo en web y se los agradecería mucho.

Un poco del código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<body>
    <span class="boligrama">
        <script src="Componentes/Action.js"></script>
    </span>
    <span class="acordeon">
    ...
    </span>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media(min-width: 700px){
            span.acordeon{
                display: block;
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media(max-width: 700px){
            span.boligrama{
                display: block;
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

El script que se encuentra en la clase boligrama, me dibuja una estructura con HTML5 canvas, y la clase acordeon, me realiza un acordeon que despliega información. Eso ya lo tengo implementado y de hecho lo tengo en archivos separados. Mi primera idea fue unir el llamado al script y el acordeon en un mismo archivo y tratar de hacer el cambio con un media queries pero no supe como hacerlo bien. Basicamente lo que quiero es que al hacer el tamaño de la pantalla menor a 800px aparezca el acordeon y desaparezca el canvas, en caso contrario, solo aparezca el canvas.

Comment: Con css y las media querys

Comment: Pero eso lo haría en un archivo externo, o como podría hacer se "Switch" entre ambos archivos HTML? NO me queda claro aún.

Comment: Pro favor, muestra el código que tengas hasta el momento

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo, la solución fue hacer una regla con JavaScript. Con los media queries no fue posible pues me veía muy limitado.